# Push notification from azure blobstore to arbitrary number of webapps

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I use data stored in in a blob for some configuration for some azure web apps, and I'd like to react to changes to it in near realtime. Currently I just set a timed event and periodically check if the etag of the blob has changed, and if it has then download the new blob.

This is ok, but I don't want to poll the blob too often, and I also want to be reactive. The devs changing the values in the blob want to be able to test the new values quickly.

The web app scales up and down, and each instance of the web app needs to download the config file. So, as far as I can tell, I can't just use the event system that azure storage has, as that would only send a notification to one instance.

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you want to centralize manage your azure web apps. Once some config has been changed, your app services should reload configs on time automatically. Actually, [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/) provides this kind of functionality.

You can also config the condition to reload all configs in code. This is a [.net core sample here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-aspnet-core?tabs=core5x). And you find other samples under the `Enable dynamic configuration` blade.